# Which one of these sentences is more correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

If I'm explaining a specific rule to someone. I would like to say that the rule has exceptions. How to choose the correct proposition?

1. This rule is not valid **in** all cases.
2. This rule is not valid **for** all cases.

Are these sentences commonly used among native speakers? or Is there more powerful sentence?

**Edit:**
I'm teaching Arabic to someone. I need to tell him if he sees a specific character at the end of a word. This word is categorized under "feminine words". But it is not a general rule. It has some exceptions. There are some irregular words.

Comment: What are the "cases"? Can you be more specific? Are they items, situations, activities, etc.? It could be the difference between "involved in" vs. "applies to".

Comment: @user3169 I edited the question.

Comment: Personally, in this context, I would use *in*; you are simply saying that the rule isn't always valid.  *For* is more often used in formal logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your sentences are equally correct

> This rule is not valid **in** all cases
>   This rule is not valid **for** all cases

after which you might enumerate or explain the cases, or you can simply say

> **There are exceptions to this rule.**

Answer (score 0):

As Peter has said, both sentences are correct.  *For all cases* has the approximate meaning of *if applied to all cases*, while *in all cases* has the approximate meaning of *if made a part of all cases*.  As you can see, either meaning is equivalent in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that in a general sense there is not much difference, but based on the usage of "cases" meaning "words" in the Edited Question, I would use:

> This rule is not valid **for** all *words*.

"This rule is not valid *in* all words." would not make sense.

So it depends on the context or the specific meaning of generalized words.